# Combinations Optimization in Python

Tags: python, pandas, combinations

I'm planning a golf trip with 6 people, trying to optimize the pairings. I start with the number of combinations and then randomly sample for 5 rounds. My goal is to create the cross matrix of row[a,b,c,d,e,f] with column [a,b,c,d,e,f] and to then find the combination of groupings that minimizes the number of 1s.

```
import pandas
from itertools import permutations, combinations
players = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
z = pd.DataFrame(combinations(players,3)
for i in z.index:
    players = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
    players.remove(z.loc[i,0])
    players.remove(z.loc[i,1])
    players.remove(z.loc[i,2])
    z.loc[i,3] = players[0]
    z.loc[i,4] = players[1]
    z.loc[i,5] = players[2] #just to fill out the rest of the matrix
```

```
z = 
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  a  b  c  d  e  f
1  a  b  d  c  e  f
2  a  b  e  c  d  f
3  a  b  f  c  d  e
4  a  c  d  b  e  f
5  a  c  e  b  d  f
6  a  c  f  b  d  e
7  a  d  e  b  c  f
8  a  d  f  b  c  e
9  a  e  f  b  c  d

v = z.sample(5)

opt = pd.DataFrame([], index = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'],columns = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'])
g = pd.concat([v[1].value_counts(),v[2].value_counts()]).sort_index().groupby(level = 0).sum() #pairings count for A
g
Out[116]: 
b    3
c    1
d    1
e    3
f    2
```

Any ideas/functions that could help me here? I can get the first column using value_counts() in columns 1 & 2 since column 0 is always 'a',but unsure how to fill out the rest of the matrix. TIA!

Solution would look like this:

```
   a    b    c    d    e    f
a  0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
b  3  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
c  1  1    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
d  1  3    3    0.0  0.0  0.0
e  3  1    3    1    0.0  0.0
f  2  1    2    2    2    0.0
```

#For this sample

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5
3  a  b  f  c  d  e
2  a  b  e  c  d  f
5  a  c  e  b  d  f
1  a  b  d  c  e  f
9  a  e  f  b  c  d
```

Comment: Can you describe the logic that you're using to arrive at the `number of 1s`? It's not immediately obvious what you mean.

Comment: Can you give the expected output? Maybe using a smaller example if needed.

Comment: so i think the optimal solution will be where the number of 1s in the optimization matrix is minimized, which would mean that a player only plays with another player in 1 round.

Comment: expected output would be a matrix with 6 rows, 6 columns, with numbers in it. added it to description

Comment: @user2109046 I meant the exact expected output, with the correct numbers

Answer (score 0):

Ended up with this solution:

```
opt_score = 11
opt_v = ''
opt_cross = ''
k=0
while k < 50000:
    s = 2
    v = z.sample(s)
    v = v[['group1','group2']]
    p = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
    all_strings = []
    for a in p:
        letter_string = ''
        for i in v.index:
            if a in v.loc[i,'group1']:
                letter_string += v.loc[i,'group1']
            else:
                letter_string += v.loc[i,'group2']
        letter_string = letter_string.replace(a,'')
        all_strings.append(letter_string)
    g = pd.DataFrame(all_strings, columns = ['C'])
    g2 = g['C'].str.split('',expand = True)
    g2 = g2.T
    g2.drop([0,s*2+1], axis = 0, inplace = True)
    g2.columns = p
    opt = pd.DataFrame([], index = p,columns = p)
    opt.fillna(0, inplace = True)
    for a in g2.columns:
        n = g2[a].value_counts().to_frame()
        n.loc[a] = 0
        opt = pd.concat([opt,n]).sort_index().groupby(level = 0).sum()
    if (opt[opt == 1.].count().sum()/2 < opt_score) & (opt[opt == 0.].count().sum() == 6):
    #if (opt.loc['g','h'] == 3.) & (opt.loc['a','b'] >= 1.) & (opt.loc['a','e'] >= 1.) & (opt.loc['c','d'] >= 2.):
        opt_score = opt[opt == 1.].count().sum()/2
        opt_v = v[['group1','group2']]
        opt_cross = opt
        
    k+=1
```

Essentially creates strings of all the grouping combinations and then removes the letter that you are looking for, then does value_counts from there. Super messy but got the solution I was looking for. Key was sort_index().groupby(level = 0).sum(). Starts with optimization score of 11, trying to minimize the number of zeros.